# Mixed effects model specification with lmer

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures

I have pain-score outcomes for some patients in my database. Many individuals have repeated pain scores across multiple days. My main question of interest is *"Does the treatment (as opposed to being in the control) improve post-operative pain scores?*

Since each individual may have multiple pain scores recorded over several days, I believe a repeated measures/mixed effects model would be appropriate?

However, I am undecided on which model would make more sense? One caveat is that an individual patient may be in **both** the treatment and control group.

Model 1:

```
model = lmer(pain_score ~ class + (1 | person_id), data = pain_score_data)
```

Model 2:

```
model1 = lmer(pain_score ~ class + (1 + class|person_id), data = pain_score_data)
```

The data looks like this:

```
  person_id       pain_score days_since_operation        class
  123                   6       0                         Treatment
  123                   0       1                         Treatment
  222                   2       0                         Treatment
  222                   3       5                         Control
  324                   2       0                         Control
```

Comment: Welcome to cv, Jamie! Just a short question: could it be that you meant `class` and not `treatment`  in you model 1? And another one: can you disclose what treatment and control are (ok, if this is confidential), and how large the percentage of patients in both groups is, roughly?

Comment: Yes, I meant class? The treatment group represents a therapeutic drug (roughly represents 70% of the data)

Comment: tx - Is it always such that, if a person appears in both groups, they have been in the treatment group before? I am not sure what implications this would have for the interpretation of results (I am not a medic)

Comment: Yes, exactly! The treatment was administered from 2010-2019. The treatment was no longer administered afterwards, so if an individual was both in the control and treatment, they were initially in the treatment group then the control group. @Ute

Comment: Jamie, 1) I got doubts about using linear mixed models (lmm) for pain scores. Pain scores are ordinal data, and lmm were made for normally distributed data. Is it common practice to use lmm for pain scores? 2) How many of the persons have been in both groups (first in trt, then ctrl), how many solely in treatment and how many in control only?